# Extjs htmleditor grow to fit the contents of its value

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, html-editor

How can I grow extjs htmleditor with it's content value with having no scroll bars (just like extjs textArea grow.).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [shrinkWrap](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor-cfg-shrinkWrap) config.

*If this property is a number, it is interpreted as follows:

0: Neither width nor height depend on content. This is equivalent to false.
1: Width depends on content (shrink wraps), but height does not.
2: Height depends on content (shrink wraps), but width does not. The default.
3: Both width and height depend on content (shrink wrap). This is equivalent to true.
In CSS terms, shrink-wrap width is analogous to an inline-block element as opposed to a block-level element. Some container layouts always shrink-wrap their children, effectively ignoring this property (e.g., Ext.layout.container.HBox, Ext.layout.container.VBox, Ext.layout.component.Dock).
Defaults to: 2*

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Ext.application({

    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        new Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor({
            renderTo: document.body,
            height: 22,
            width: 300,
            defaultValue: '',
            listeners: {
                initialize: function(field) {
                    var body = field.getEditorBody();
                    body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
                    Ext.DomHelper.applyStyles(body, {
                        'word-wrap': 'break-word'
                    });
                    this.getToolbar().hide();
                },
                change: function(field) {
                    var body = field.getEditorBody();
                    field.setHeight(body.offsetHeight);
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Sencha fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/271j